# XSL1.0 - Apply-templates only takes the first child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, apply-templates

I'm working on this new addition to report `dip-sensor` data. But I'm running into a problem where `apply-templates` only checks for the first `<filter>` node and not the rest.

I also have tried changing the code to use a `for-each` instead of `apply-templates`, but still no luck.

**XML File:**

```
...
</dlp-sensor>
<dlp-sensor>
  <name>DLPSensor.1</name>
  <description/>
  <property>0</property>
  <filter-list>
    <filter>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <source>
        <type>6</type>
        <any/>
      </source>
      <destination>
        <type>6</type>
        <any/>
      </destination>
      <dlp-action>
        <smtp-action>lock</smtp-action>
        <action>drop</action>
        <log>1</log>
        <alarm>0</alarm>
      </dlp-action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <source>
        <type>3</type>
        <email-addr>blah@uneducated.edu</email-addr>
      </source>
      <destination>
        <type>1</type>
        <host-ip-addr>192.1.1.1</host-ip-addr>
      </destination>
      <dlp-action>
        <smtp-action>block</smtp-action>
        <action>drop</action>
        <log>1</log>
        <alarm>DLP</alarm>
      </dlp-action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <source>
        <type>4</type>
        <auth-user>ninja-hacker</auth-user>
      </source>
      <destination>
        <type>3</type>
        <email-addr>ceo@companyowner.edu</email-addr>
      </destination>
      <dlp-action>
        <smtp-action>strip</smtp-action>
        <action>block</action>
        <log>0</log>
        <alarm>0</alarm>
      </dlp-action>
    </filter>
  </filter-list>
</dlp-sensor>
<dlp-sensor>
...
```

**XSL v1.0:**

```
<xsl:template match="dlp-sensor" mode="dlpDetails">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="second_head"><xsl:call-template name="getResource"><xsl:with-param name="resID" select="'Source'"/></xsl:call-template></th>
            <th class="second_head"><xsl:call-template name="getResource"><xsl:with-param name="resID" select="'Destination'"/></xsl:call-template></th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="filter-list/filter" mode="filtering"/>

    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="filter" mode="filtering">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="source/type"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="destination/type"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result:**
`66`

**Desired:**
`663143`

The results only show `66` but should show `663143` because it should have captured all the `source/type` and `destination/type` from all three `<filter>` nodes in the `<filter-list>`.

There can be any amount of `<dlp-sensor>` and each might have a different amount of `<filter>`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code appears to be working for me. What does the rest of your XSLT look like? How are you running it? What processor are you using?

Comment: Whatever you do, your error is not in the code you show. Copied verbatim from your question, your code works: http://www.xmlplayground.com/YlH4I0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a spelling error:

<**xsl:apply-templates** select="filter-list/filter" mode="filtering"/>

also perhaps try something like 
`<xsl:for-each select="dlp-sensor/filter-list">
followed with <**xsl:apply-templates** select="filter">`

Comment: Oh I had a typo when typing into this thread. That wasn't causing the issue for this `apply-template` to not work. I have tried the `<xsl:for-each select="dlp-sensor/filter-list">` no luck.